# Specific word to replace "set somebody up for something [positive]"

Tags: single-word-requests

In the following sentence:

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can set
> companies up for continued progress in the long term.

I would like to replace "set ____ up" with a non-phrasal word. What alternatives might be appropriate here?

Comment: Your question is a word to replace "X can set companies up for continued progress". If we loosen the requirement, you could reword this as "X is conducive to a company's continued progress".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**"Prime"** or **"dispose"** could be used appropriately.

The definition of "prime" ([HERE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/prime)) that applies to this situation would be **"prepare (someone) for a situation or task, typically by supplying them with relevant information."**  The "market conditions" prepare/groom companies for "continued progress..."

The sentence with "prime" would be either:

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can prime companies for continued progress in the long term.

OR

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can prime companies to continue progress(ing) in the long term.

Note: The "-ing" in the second example can be added/omitted.

The definition of "dispose" ([HERE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispose)) that applies would be **"to give a tendency to."**  The "market conditions" give a tendency to have "continued progress..."

The sentence with "dispose" would be either:

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can dispose companies to continue progress(ing) in the long term.

OR

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can dispose companies toward continued progress in the long term.

Note: The "-ing" in the first example can be added/omitted.

Comment: or "predispose", if you want to imply "set up ahead of time or as a consequence"

Comment: @sintax I chose "dispose" instead of "predispose" because the latter implies that something is inherent and out of one's control.  For example, "I am predisposed to having high blood pressure."  It depends on the subtext, but I prefer "dispose" for this situation.

Comment: IMHO - prime would be much more readily understood in this sense than dispose. FWIW - similar to the way one "never" hears "gruntled" in actual conversation, only "disgruntled"; one would much more commonly hear "predispose" used in this sense than "dispose". (western USA)

Comment: @geneSummons I completely agree.  Also, "dispose" is "get rid of by throwing away or giving or selling to someone else," which further adds to the confusion.  This is why I put "prime" before "dispose."  However, some people may be familiar with this definition (setting someone up for something) of "dispose," so I wouldn't completely rule it out.

Answer (score 16):

"**Position**" would be my choice, as it's a common construction in the business world and would seem to be apt for this scenario (*position companies for continue progress*). In fact, the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/position) example definition is almost precisely the scenario in the question:

> positioned the company in the global market

Comment: Please don’t use backticks on Stack Exchange, other than on the computer-related sites (like [SO] and [SU]).

Comment: Also, the question seems to be asking for a verb, and, while “position” can be used as a verb, you have quoted a noun definition.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the noun catch.  Updated to the verb, which is a direct match. As for the backticks, next we'll be battling over tabs vs. spaces.

Answer (score 9):

The market conditions give the companies the tools they need, so they [**equip**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equip) them:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : to furnish for service or action by appropriate provisioning
>    // *equip* an army

Used in the example sentence:

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can equip companies for continued progress in the long term.

Answer (score 6):

As the context is economic, you could use *[**enable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enable)*.

Example:

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can *enable* companies to continue progress in the long term.

(You could also use ***[stimulate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stimulate)***, ***[facilitate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facilitate)*** or ***[instil](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instil)***. Or perhaps ***[inculcate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inculcate)***.)

Comment: I don’t know why you associate the economic context with ‘‘enable’’.  Good weather can enable me to have a picnic (outside).  Good grades in high school (ages 15-18) enable me to get into a prestigious college.

Comment: @Scott: Because 'enable' is used quite a lot in economic contexts.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other excellent answers you may also consider indicating that the 'current situation can **encourage** companies to..." as opposed to saying it "**can** set them up"

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions can
> prompt (or provoke, or encourage) companies to employ (or look to
> employ) strategies that support their continued progress in the long
> term

Answer (score 1):

- ***facilitate***
- ***enable***
- ***support***
- ***spawn***
- ***foster***
- ***catalyze*** (kind of business jargon, not proper English)
- ***seed***
- etc.

You wanted single-word. Multiword phrases include ***serve as the basis for***...

Answer (score 1):

**Stage**, shortened form of **set the stage**

> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions
> *stage* companies for continued progress in the long term.
>
> Past experience suggests that these kind of market conditions *set
> the stage* for continued progress in the long term.

**Examples:**

- > This is used in sports a lot. When a team is losing, the announcers might say, "the stage is set for a comeback. [[NYTimes]](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/09/sports/tennis/serena-williams-indian-wells.html)
- > Example from performing arts: [[Forbes]](https://www.forbes.com/sites/hughmcintyre/2020/06/25/blackpinks-duet-with-lady-gaga-set-the-stage-for-their-comeback-single-how-you-like-that/#c65481d55f07)
- > Example from Finance: [[Newsbreak]](https://www.newsbreak.com/news/1483675400001/agco-corporation-setting-the-stage-for-a-comeback) [[AMM]](https://www.amm.com/Magazine/2507042/Market-Spotlight/Producers-see-destocking-stableorder-rates-setting-stage-for-an-upturn.html)

Comment: Very helpful, examples made it all the more compelling. Thank you